# UIpopoverviewcontroller click the the button hide the popoverview and open imagepicker from parent view

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, xcode4.2

Hi all i'm new iphone developer,

I have problem while open the uiimagepickercontroller.

I have option take the photo and open gallery in popoverview to take the photo and open the camera that time hide the popoverview and open gallery hide the popover and open the imagepicker from parent view controller imagepicker should not open from popover view controller.

please share your ideas.

Answer (score 2):

// For opening camera

```
-(void)btnCameraClicked {
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
        imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        [self presentModalViewController:imgPicker animated:YES];
    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Camera is not Available" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
}
```

// For opening image picker controller

```
-(void)btnGalleryClicked {
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {
        imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        [self presentModalViewController:imgPicker animated:YES];
    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"Photos are not available" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
}
```

After this you can use ImagePicking Methods like :

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use UIPopoverControllerDelegate method

```
-(void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController;
```